# python equivalent of perl sort by hash value

Tags: python, sorting

I'm looking to replicate the following perl code in python. The object is to obtain an array of hash/dictionary keys sorted by multiple hash/dictionary values. Example perl code:

```
my $hash = {
 'item1'=> {'id'=>'a', 'pos'=>6},
 'item2'=> {'id'=>'a', 'pos'=>7},
 'item3'=> {'id'=>'b', 'pos'=>4},
 'item4'=> {'id'=>'a', 'pos'=>5},
 'item5'=> {'id'=>'b', 'pos'=>2},
};

my @keys = sort {
  $hash->{$a}->{id} cmp $hash->{$b}->{id} ||
  $hash->{$a}->{pos} <=> $hash->{$b}->{pos}
} keys %$hash;

print "@keys\n";
```

This sorts by `id` lexically, then by `pos` numerically, so the expected outcome is:

```
item4 item1 item2 item5 item3
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I'm not that fluent in perl... if I understand correctly the result should be sorted by `id` first and then by `pos`, giving items 4,1,2,5,3?

Comment: Expected outcome: item4 item1 item2 item5 item3. So yes, the result should be sorted by 'id' then by 'pos' (numerically).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sorted`:

```
[k for k, v in sorted(hash.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1].id, item[1].pos))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import attrgetter
sorted(hash, key=lambda k:attrgetter('id', 'pos')(hash[k]))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `itemgetter`?

Comment: @stranac, attrgetter is like itemgetter, but for attributes

Comment: Yeah, I know what `attrgetter` is, but `'id'` and `'pos'` are not the dict's attributes, they're it's keys.

Comment: @stranac, ok. I was basing it off ecatmur's answer which uses attributes. itemgetter would be correct if it's keys